# React Native release build with Metro

Tags: react-native

At first when i was creating a new react native project the release folder is automatically created but now it is not creating so now the app only runs when its connect to the metro and the metro runs on port 8081 only .

please tell me now can I make a release build automatically so that when I am not near the computer i can show everyone how my app works

Comment: can you not just build an APK for android and share the APK file to other stakeholders? I don't think if you build the APK file correctly for dev or preview, it would need the dev client to be running. Also check out this one as well! https://docs.expo.dev/develop/development-builds/share-with-your-team/